# Using URL Encode successfully

Tags: php

I'm building a navigation structure in a series `foreach` loops. This navigation currently works successfully, however it does not deal with the '&' character within URL's.

For example I have the following link code:

```
$nav .= "<li><a href='$url$item->catname/$item->subcatname/$subcat->subcatname'>".$subcat->subcatname ."</a>";
```

I have tried the following:

```
$nav .= "<li><a href=" . urlencode('$url$item->catname/$item->subcatname/$subcat->subcatname') . ">".$subcat->subcatname ."</a>";
```

Although this displays the php markup. What is the best solution here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You're using your [quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) wrong